# Volley SSL - Hostname was not verified

Tags: java, android, ssl, android-volley, self-signed

I'm developing an Android App and I need to access an HTTPS address. I'm using Volley to request my data, but now i'm getting this error `com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: Hostname '<address>' was not verified`

To get the SSL factory i make this:

```
private static SSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory() {
    SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = null;


    try {
        final CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        final BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(sContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cert)) ;

        Certificate certificate;
        try {
            certificate = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(bis);
        } finally {
            bis.close();
        }

        final String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", certificate);

        final String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);
        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        socketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
    return socketFactory;
}
```

The queue initialization:

```
final HttpStack stack = new HurlStack(null, getSocketFactory());
final Cache cache = new NoCache();
final Network network = new BasicNetwork(stack);
sRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
sRequestQueue.start();
```

Here's the stacktrace:

```
    com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: Hostname 'url' was not verified
09-04 11:15:33.198   W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:151)
09-04 11:15:33.198   W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
09-04 11:15:33.198   W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.io.IOException: Hostname 'hml.services.vivara.com.br' was not verified
09-04 11:15:33.198   W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:201)
09-04 11:15:33.198   W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:151)
09-04 11:15:33.198   W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
09-04 11:15:33.198   W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
09-04 11:15:33.198   W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
09-04 11:15:33.198   W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
09-04 11:15:33.198   W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:208)
09-04 11:15:33.198   W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
09-04 11:15:33.198   W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
09-04 11:15:33.198   W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:240)
09-04 11:15:33.198   W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:210)
09-04 11:15:33.198   W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:106)
09-04 11:15:33.198   W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
```

I searched for the error, but I didn't find anything for my case. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's assume your server app is hosting inside a server machine which has a server certificate in which `"Issued to"` is `"localhost"`, for example. Then, inside verify method you can verify `"localhost"`.

```
HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        HostnameVerifier hv =
            HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
        return hv.verify("localhost", session);
    }
};
```

You can read more at the following links:

1. [HostnameVerifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier.html)

   > It is to be used during a handshake if the URL's hostname does not match the peer's identification hostname.
2. [Common Problems with Hostname Verification](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#CommonHostnameProbs)

   > One reason this can happen is due to a server configuration error. The
   >   server is configured with a certificate that does not have a subject
   >   or subject alternative name fields that match the server you are
   >   trying to reach...

Then, in your **Volley** app, you can create a `HurlStack`, overriding `createConnection` in which `setHostnameVerifier` for the `httpsURLConnection`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The method `createConnection` in `HurlStack` returns a `HttpURLConnection` and _not_ a `HttpsURLConnection`. So, there is no `setHostnameVerifier `. Please provide more detailed answer how to create a custom `HurlStack` object for this case. Thanks!

Comment: @toom you can find an example at my another answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673568/does-android-volley-support-ssl/32674422#32674422

Answer (score -2):

This is a possible solution

```
HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: What's that supposed to be?

Answer (score -6):

This error occurs when your internet gets disconnected during the http request.
So make sure your internet is consistent and then check.

Comment: I think you can find the cause of this error at https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#CommonHostnameProbs