# HttpURLConnnection request failures on Android 6.0 (MarshMallow)

Tags: android-volley, httpurlconnection, http-status-code-401, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am using Google's Volley library for my application project , that targets minimum api level 14.So, Volley library uses HttpURLConnection as the NetworkClient.

Therefore , there should not be any issue related to Removal of Apache HTTPClient. However, I have done the configuration required for 6.0 Sdk i.e compileSdkVersion 23, build-tool-version 23.0.1 and build:gradle:1.3.1' and even tried adding useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'. Have updated the same for Volley library project in my application.

Recently ,I tried to run my app on Android 6.0 (MarshMallow), my project compiles and runs. But those requests that require authentication headers are failing on MarshMallow with:

> BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401  com.android.volley.AuthFailureError

However the same is running on all Api level below 23.

I have checked the headers many times.Strangely, those requests that do not require authentication are giving response with 200 OK.

Right now I am totally clueless what is breaking the requests, does anybody have any idea what has changed in new Version that HttpURLConnection request fails for only Api level 23? Is anybody else using Volley and facing similar issue?

Here is my CustomRequest Class

```
public class CustomRequest extends Request<Void> {

int id, cmd;
Map<String, String> params;
BaseModel model;

public CustomRequest(int method, int cmd, String url, Map<String, String> params, int id, BaseModel model) {
    super(method, url, null);
    this.id = id;
    this.cmd = cmd;
    this.params = params;
    this.model = model;

    if (method == Method.GET) {
        setUrl(buildUrlForGetRequest(url));
    }

    Log.v("Volley", "Making request to: " + getUrl());
}

private String buildUrlForGetRequest(String url) {
    if (params == null || params.size() == 0) return url;

    StringBuilder newUrl = new StringBuilder(url);
    Set<Entry<String, String>> paramPairs = params.entrySet();
    Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iter = paramPairs.iterator();

    newUrl.append("?");
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, String> param = iter.next();
        newUrl
            .append(param.getKey())
            .append("=")
            .append(param.getValue());
        if (iter.hasNext()) newUrl.append("&");
    }

    return newUrl.toString();
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();

    headers.put("X-Api-Version", Contract.API_VERSION);
    headers.put("X-Client", "android");
    String accessToken = APP.getInstance().getToken();
    if (!accessToken.equals("")) {
        headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);    
    }

    return headers;
}

@Override
protected Response<Void> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    Exception ex;
    try {
        String jsonString = new String(
                response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        JsonNode json = new ObjectMapper().readTree(jsonString);
        if (model != null) model.parse(id, json);
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new EventResponse(cmd, true, null));
        return Response.success(null, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response)); //Doesn't return anything. BaseModel.parse() does all the storage work.
    } catch (NoMoreDataException e) {
        ex = e;
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new NoMoreDataModel(cmd, e));
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new EventResponse(cmd, false, null));
        return Response.success(null, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ex = e;
        Log.e("CustomRequest", Log.getStackTraceString(e));

        String message = APP.getInstance().getString(R.string.failedRequest);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(e.getMessage()))
            message = e.getMessage();
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new ErrorEventModel(cmd, message, e));
        return Response.error(new ParseError(ex));
    }
}

@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    return params;
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(Void response) {
    Log.v("Volley", "Delivering result: " + getUrl());
}

@Override
public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
    Log.e("CustomRequest", "Delivering error: Request=" + getUrl() + " | Error=" + error.toString());

    String message = APP.getInstance().getString(R.string.failedRequest);
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new ErrorEventModel(cmd, message, error));
}
```

}

Only difference I found between Api 23 and others is the **HostNameVerifier**.
For Api level 23 : com.android.okhttp.internal.tls.OkHostnameVerifier
For Api level <23 : javax.net.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier.

Comment: Pls post your code and logcat information if available.

Comment: Sorry , my reputation doesn't allow me to post more code.Logcat shows the above code snippet error only. 
Please see my findings , can this be the reason for the issue.

Comment: I think you can try hardcode the access token (you can use Postman to get a new token, then paste into your code). My volley project with bearer token works in API23 emulator. Make sure you have a valid/unexpired token :)

Comment: Tried hardcoding.No luck :(
After all these requests are working on api below 23 with same codebase and token getting read correctly.

Comment: Do you have control over the server side app? If yes, try debugging it. Is is Asp.Net Web API?

Comment: Use 'Log.i("LOG",accessToken);' below 'String accessToken = APP.getInstance().getToken();' then post new logcat pls

Comment: Sorry reputation issue.
Logcat Error:
 D/Volley: [236] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] https://api-qa.theteamie.com/app/newsfeed.json?page=1&items_per_page=30 0x7d26a972 NORMAL 4> [lifetime=7600], [size=81], [rc=401], [retryCount=0]

E/Volley: [236] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for https://api-qa.theteamie.com/app/newsfeed.json?page=1&items_per_page=30

 I/LOG: a2457965e8b577522ec3f80653d19b9d46ac75bd

Comment: Don't have access to server side app. Using REST API.
I have a strong feeling that OkHostNameVerifier is not able to read Authorization Header.Cause those requests that don't need this header are executing.Can you  please check in your Volley project what is the  HttpURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier for Api 23.Is it possible for you?

Comment: Since you have an authentication error, where is your code to add an authentication header ?

Comment: Server side is HTTPS? If NO, I dont think it is because of HostNameVerifier. If YES, you need to call setHostNameVerifier, read my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673568/does-android-volley-support-ssl/32674422#32674422

Comment: @BladeCoder Pls see the getHeaders() method in the above code.There ,I am adding Authorization header with access token value.

Comment: @BNK .Yes it is HTTPS and I have already implemented setHostNameVerifier .Don't know what's getting wrong :( But Thanks for trying to  help!

Comment: If your server app is published in Internet, pls tell me its Url and essential parameters so that I can check more

Comment: Volley's HurlStack(HttpURLConnection)  is not reading Authorization header for Api 23 therefore its 401 UnAuthorized everytime for requests that need this header.Tried calling requests using the same access token that is passed through postman, working fine.
So there's no issue with access  token.But why its not setting Authorization  header .Is there way to figure out?

Comment: I don't why you said that :), you can find `map.putAll(request.getHeaders());
        map.putAll(additionalHeaders);` inside `performRequest` of HurlStack.java

Comment: @BNK I know this was a strange issue which I was facing and you said it worked fine for you.But found a solution that works for all newer and older versions.
You may check my answer.Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

After checking the Server side of my application, found the reason behind the issue.
For Android 6.0(MarshMallow) the headers were becoming empty and this was not the case with other versions.

**So the fix that worked for me:**

Created and Added a new custom header *X-Proxy-No-Redirect => 1* and passed along with other headers.

**Theory behind it:**

There is a API server to which we send request, then the API server redirects the request to corresponding site based on the oAuth token
While redirecting 
For the redirection to happen, there are two ways to do that

1 - We just send a response back to the caller stating to redirect to a certain page. Then the caller(Networking library) takes care of redirection

2 - API server will itself makes the redirect request and get the response and then pass to caller

Earlier we were using the Method 1.

On Android 6.0 - The networking lib(Volley) doesn't seem to set all the headers while making the redirection request.
Once this new header is set, Method 2 will come into effective.

**P.S** This fix was applicable for my application project , maybe not for others.Just providing what was wrong and what helped me.