# Volley ServerError Code : 400 ONLY in Android 6 (Marshmallow)

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm doing a simple GET request using Volley library in Android. Lately I've discovered that in Android 6 (Marshmallow) I always get to the `onErrorResponse` callback, there is no error message but the error code is 400.
All my other nearly identical requests work perfectly in Android 6. Only this one is the problematic. 
When I paste the request URL into a browser, it works. So the problem is not from server-side.

I also tried adding headers, but that didn't help.

Comment: Look in to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288792/httpurlconnnection-request-failures-on-android-6-0-marshmallow

Comment: it didn't help me unfortunately..
I tried adding the custom header `X-Proxy-No-Redirect` with value : `1` , but it had no effect at all

Comment: check the http code u get in the browser

Comment: in the browser there is no error code, because it works perfectly on browser. If I paste the request url in browser I receive the correct response. The problem occurs only in the app

Comment: @BVtp did u solve this issue?

Comment: i HAVE THE SAME ISSUE!!!! UGGHHH

Answer (score 1):

This problem came to me also, and not the content-type was the problem.
For me also on Android 7 and up the URL what I used was working correctly, on browser also, but when checked it on Android 6 it threw me the same problem what you wrote.
It's because probably your URL contains spaces.

**Resolution:**

```
String url = "http://your_url.com/file.php?data=" + sendJson;
url = url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

And the problem is gone!

Answer (score 1):

I also use Volley and had the same issue.
The problem is that on **Android 6.X Marshmallow** the url parameters **are not being encoded** in UTF-8 on GET requests. Dunno why...

So if you send a GET request like

```html
http://example.com/api?key=my value
```

or

```html
http://example.com/api?place=café
```

it will be sent as follows:

### On Android 6.X

```html
http://example.com/api?key=my value
http://example.com/api?place=café
```

*(returns: 400 - HTTP_BAD_REQUEST)*

---

### Other versions

```html
http://example.com/api?key=my+value
http://example.com/api?place=caf%C3%A9
```

*(if your serve is working properly, returns: 200 - HTTP_OK)*

---

So, my workaround was call

```
URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8");
```

for every single parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Replace empty character with "%20" from your URL.
 String url = "https://zxasd/asd";
 url = url.replaceAll(" " , "%20");