# How do I programatically extract a certificate from a site and add it to my keystore?

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying fix--

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Found solution--
   [Does Android Volley support SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673568/does-android-volley-support-ssl)

But in this I have to integrate My_cert.crt file in APK which may change or expire in future.

I tried [this](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-do-i-programatically-extract-a-certificate-from-a-site-and-add-it-to-my-keystore) link. But getting no certificates chain empty.

Is there another way of doing it. Please share. Thanks in advance.