# Read in PKCS12/P12 Client Cert file for Android App

Tags: android, ssl, fileinputstream, client-certificates, self-signed

I am trying to use a Client Certificate inside of my Android app so that I can insure HTTPS communication only with people who use the app or have the cert.

I have the certificate in my res/raw folder. And Android Studio sees it when I start typing in "R.raw."

However, when I use any of the following code, the variable comes back as having a "null" value:

```
FileInputStream fis = null;
fis = (FileInputStream) getClass().getResourceAsStream(String.valueOf(R.raw.clientcert2));
```

or

```
InputStream fis = getClass().getResourceAsStream("raw/clientcert2.p12");
```

or

```
InputStream fis = null;
fis= (InputStream) getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.clientcert2);
```

The last one actually crashes the app, which makes me think it's not even close to correct. It crashes with the following error:

```
09-10 08:13:06.677  10310-10310/com.example.agenice.clientcert E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.agenice.clientcert, PID: 10310
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.agenice.clientcert/com.example.agenice.clientcert.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
at com.example.agenice.clientcert.GetCert.getThisCert(MainActivity.java:92)
at com.example.agenice.clientcert.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As a side note - Yes, I know that if someone gets the APK, they can simply unzip the package and grab the cert. Which is why this isn't the final form of the app. It's only step one in the process.  In the iOS version of the App, I was able to import the p12 file, turn the binary into a string, export the string to the log and then use that as the certificate.  This eliminated the need for having the certificate file added to the app.  So, that's where this whole thing is headed. If anybody has a quick and easy way to do that, that would be great. For now, all I need is to figure out why this part isn't working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE FOR YOUR  `NullPointerException`**

From your **logcat** information, `getResources()` in `GetCert.getThisCert()` caused NullPointerException. It looks like that you have not passed `Context` from your **Activity** to `GetCert` class. So, please update your code and check the result.

**END OF UPDATE**

You can refer to my following code:

```
private TrustManager[] getWrappedTrustManagers(TrustManager[] trustManagers) {
        final X509TrustManager originalTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];
        return new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return originalTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
                    }

                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                        try {
                            originalTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(certs, authType);
                        } catch (CertificateException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                        try {
                            originalTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(certs, authType);
                        } catch (CertificateException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
        };
    }

private SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory_Certificate(String keyStoreType, int keystoreResId)
        throws CertificateException, KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {

    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    InputStream caInput = getResources().openRawResource(keystoreResId);

    Certificate ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
    caInput.close();

    if (keyStoreType == null || keyStoreType.length() == 0) {
        keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
    }
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
    keyStore.load(null, null);
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

    String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
    tmf.init(keyStore);

    TrustManager[] wrappedTrustManagers = getWrappedTrustManagers(tmf.getTrustManagers());

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, wrappedTrustManagers, null);

    return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
}

private SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory_KeyStore(String keyStoreType, int keystoreResId, String keyPassword)
            throws CertificateException, KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {

        InputStream caInput = getResources().openRawResource(keystoreResId);

        // creating a KeyStore containing trusted CAs

        if (keyStoreType == null || keyStoreType.length() == 0) {
            keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        }
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);

        keyStore.load(caInput, keyPassword.toCharArray());

        // creating a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in the KeyStore

        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        TrustManager[] wrappedTrustManagers = getWrappedTrustManagers(tmf.getTrustManagers());

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, wrappedTrustManagers, null);

        return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    }
```

Then call one of the two following (one for keystore file, the other one for certificate file):

```
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = getSSLSocketFactory_KeyStore("BKS", R.raw.androidbksv1, "123456789");
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = getSSLSocketFactory_Certificate("BKS", R.raw.androidbksv1_cert);
```

Because you have **PKCS12** file, you can use one of the two following:

```
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = getSSLSocketFactory_KeyStore("PKCS12", R.raw.androidpkcs12, "123456789");        
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = getSSLSocketFactory_Certificate("PKCS12", R.raw.androidpkcs12_cert);
```

The above code has been tested successfully in my HTTPS projects. Hope this helps!

Moreover, please clarify `The last one actually crashes the app...`, post more codes and logcat information if available.

Comment: BNK, This is awesome! Thanks. Though, I am getting the following error when i run either line.  `9885-9885/com.example.agenice.clientcert E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.agenice.clientcert, PID: 9885 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.agenice.clientcert/com.example.agenice.clientcert.Main‌​Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException` Which is eerily the same error i get when i run the other line (see edit above)

Comment: I actually got it working.  i was not creating a Context variable in my class.  adding `getThisCert(MainActivity.this)` to my call. then this to the getThisCert method `this.context = context;`. and then putting context in front of the `getResources()` call fixed my issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Oh dear, I have just updated my answer about `Context`. Glad that you have fixed :)

Comment: No worries.  you helped tremendously.  2 days of searching and you got me down the right path in a matter of minutes.  Thanks for the help!